# Segmentation fault (python3.10 und MariaDB)

Tags: python, ubuntu, mariadb, segmentation-fault

Today I added a mariaDB databank to my Discord bot but now I have the problem that I always get a segmentation fault when a new entry is added to the database.

Here is the console output with Xfaulthandler:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007fa3d7fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 324 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 607 in wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 152 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fa3ddfac700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 81 in _worker
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007fa3f8aa7740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mariadb/cursors.py", line 296 in execute
  File "/root/ayumi/Bot.py", line 217 in on_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 441 in _run_event
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80 in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909 in _run_once
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603 in run_forever
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 636 in run_until_complete
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 860 in run
  File "/root/ayumi/Bot.py", line 1381 in <module>

Extension modules: multidict._multidict, yarl._quoting_c, aiohttp._helpers, aiohttp._http_writer, aiohttp._http_parser, aiohttp._websocket, charset_normalizer.md, frozenlist._frozenlist, numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, psutil._psutil_linux, psutil._psutil_posix, mariadb._mariadb (total: 24)
Segmentation fault
```

The big problem is that I don't get an error on the pc(windows) at home and on the server(ubuntu20.04) I do.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in python itself. Being in something as OS specific as threads, even identical version on Windows as Ubuntu doesn't eliminate a python problem. I'd consider upgrading to jammy to get a new ubuntu and hence python version.

Comment: stab in the dark, but this might be from using the same mysql connection in multiple threads?  maybe avoid that and have a connection per thread